# Is there an Editor-level equivalent to Compute Instance Admin and Storage Admin?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am looking into restricting the permissions of some of our more junior team members that are not using most of their given permissions on GCP.

These users are exclusively creating+using the VM instances, as well as using GCS. They currently have the role of `Editor`. Looking at the existing per-defined roles, it looks to me as though the `Compute Instance Admin (v1)` and `Storage Admin` roles would fit their use better.

However, looking at the permission diff, a number of permissions ending in `setIamPolicy` jumps out to me as potentially dangerous. The diff also contains a number of `createTagBinding` and `deleteTagBinding` permissions that seem less alarming. *What would be the consequence of granting these?*

I'm surprised that I was not able to find a more granular `Editor`-level role, for `Compute Instance` and `Storage`. These seem to me like very common roles other companies might want to use. As far as I can tell, the `User`,`Viewer`, `Creator` or such roles specific to `Compute Instance` and `Storage` all seem to lack some core permission we currently need, such as listing buckets, creating VMs, or logging onto VMs with sudo rights. *Have I overlooked some existing roles? Is there a way to create an "intersection role", granting only permissions that both parent roles have?*

Comment: 1/2) Which permissions to grant or deny via IAM roles requires understanding what the services you are using require. Once you know that you can select from existing roles or create custom roles. Then there is the topic of isolation, which means using separate projects. Unless developers need to manage each other's instances/storage/etc, then create a separate project for each developer.

Comment: 2/2) Identity, Authorization and Security are important topics that are too large to answer the general purpose question that you asked. Unless the answer is very long, important facts and details will be left out. In security can be as dangerous as no security.

Comment: Having separate projects for each developers sounds like an interesting idea, but I don't think we can use it, as we do need developers to access each other's instances and share some data from time to time

Answer (score 2):

Basic roles like Editor, Owner, and Viewer should be avoided whenever possible.
The roles you suggested like 'Compute Instance Admin' are preferred.

In terms of permissions ending with setIamPolicy, for the Compute Instance Admin role, they apply only to compute resources like Instances, Snapshots, etc.

They are required to grant permissions to resources somebody with the Admin role creates. They do not allow to create/grant new permissions/roles that go outside of compute resources.

Have a look at the following summary. It shows a similar situation: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/resource-hierarchy-access-control